# C++ Way to remove Debugging "Flags" from executables

Tags: c++, debugging

I am building somewhat larger c++ code bases than I'm used to. I have a need for both good logging and debugging, at least to the console, and also speed.

Generally, I like to do something like this

```cpp
// Some header file

bool DEBUG = true;
```

And then in some other file

```cpp
if (DEBUG) cout << "Some debugging information" << endl;
```

The issue with this (among others) is that the branching lowers the speed of the final executable. In order to fix this, I'd have to go into the files at the end and remove all these, and then I couldn't use them again later without saving them to some other file and then putting them back in.

What is the most efficient solution to this quandry? Python decorators provide a nice approach that I'm not certain exists in CPP.

Thanks!

Comment: Just make your `bool` `const` and dead code elimination will do the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classic way is to make that `DEBUG` not a variable, but a preprocessor macro. Then you can have two builds: one with the macro defined to `1`, the other with it defined to `0` (or not defined at all, depending on how you plan to use it). Then you can either do `#ifdef` to completely remove the debug code from being seen by the compiler, or just put it into a regular `if`, the optimizer will take care of removing the branch with the constant conditional.